# Okular can't print PDF

Tags: printing, okular, cups-lpd

Okular can'r print pdf files. The document viewer prints it but all the fonts look bad (print preview works fine though). I don't know how to debug. So tired of this. What is the `cups`?
Anyone can help?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: To find out what `cups` is you can use a search engine (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CUPS or the *Common UNIX Printing System* which is used even by apple macs; even a `man cups` will show the "Apple Inc" rather prominently to show they helped fund it after they moved to OSX though it existed for years before then...)

Comment: I am so tired. I am using ubuntu for 12 years now. I feel the whole linux community is going backwards. I think I do not belong to this 'super-smart' world.

Comment: God knows why evince can't print pdf normally. God knows what is the problem with okular. Feeling frustrated.

Comment: Please read [ask] then [edit] your question with further details

Answer (score 0):

If you open Okular from the command window and try to print something you see an error

```
usage: lpr ...
```

The solution is to install a different version of lpr.

```
apt install cups-bsd
```

Then all your problems are solved.